# Cannot resolve getIntent() method in Accessibility Service class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, accessibilityservice

I am trying to send data from main activity to accessibility service class using intent but accessibility service class does not recognize `getIntent()` method. Is there any other way to pass data to an Accessibility Service class?

Comment: refer this link hope it may helps http://www.androidmads.info/2016/05/how-create-accessibility-service-in.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you add below code, where you want to start

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AccessibilityService.class);
    intent.putExtra("data","value");
    startService(intent);
```

In your AccessibilityService class, make sure you override onStartCommand() method

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    String data="";
    if(intent.getExtras().containsKey("data"))
        data = intent.getStringExtra("data");
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: I am starting and stopping the service using shared preferences , will onStartCOmmand() be called?